# Singular values and trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, singularity-theory

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are positive definite matrices,
how can I bound the singular values $\sigma(X+Y)$ in terms of the trace of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: You can't get exactly the singular values ( which, in this case. will be the eigenvalues) but you can get some estimates. The only equality you can get is their sum $= $ sum of the traces of $X$, $Y$.